# Calculate the area inside the loop

Tags: integration, area, multiple-integral

The question is - how to calculate the area inside the loop $(x+y)^3=axy$, using double integral?

In this case parameter $a$ is positive. It's easy to imagine how it looks like, depending on $a$ value. For example $a=1$:

[image: a_1]

or $a=100$

[image: a_100]

No idea how to do that.

Comment: Hint: area = $\frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2} r^2 d\theta = \frac12 \int_0^\infty x^2 dt$ where $t = \tan\theta = \frac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

In polar coordinates, the loop is described by

$$r(\theta)=\frac{a\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))^3}$$

$\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$.  The area, $A$, is then given by

$$A=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{r(\theta)}r\,dr\,d\theta \tag 1$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> From $(1)$, we have $$\begin{align}A&=\frac{a^2}2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}{(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))^6}\,d\theta\\\\&=\frac{a^2}2 \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan^2(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)}{(1+\tan(\theta))^6}\,d\theta\\\\&=\frac{a^2}2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x)^6}\,dx\\\\&=\frac{a^2}{60}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for a hint, I have also thought about polar coordinates. It's easy-to-understand for me, how to calculate the last integral, but if it's not too much trouble for you - can you explain, how did you convert my function in ortogonal coordinates to your $r(\theta)=...$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: For those, who have the same answer: just use $x = r*sin(\theta);y = r*cos(\theta)$

Comment: I see you have it.  Well done!  Yes, let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$.  Then, remember that $dx\,dy\to r\,dr\,d\theta$.